# Using a VBA For Loop to concatenate column in excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a column of data in excel. I want to loop through the data and combine the contents into a single string. I can specify the cell range, but what if the range is unknown. I want to be able to loop until the cell becomes empty. here is what I have so far.

```
Sub ConcatenationLoop()

Dim rng As Range, i As Integer

Set rng = Range("A1", "A5")

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
With Range("B1")
    If .Value = "" Then
        .Value = rng.Range("A" & i)
    Else
        .Value = .Value & ", " & rng.Range("A" & i)
    End If
End With
Next
```

is it possible to combine with something like:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
```

Much help is appreciated!

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Worksheets("YourSheetName")
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Loop it to LastRow.

Answer (score 0):

Get the first empty cell from the top using

```
lLastRow = sheet.Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Row
```

The use this in your for loop

```
For i = 1 To lLastRow
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that it will stop at the first blank cell downwards. The op Data could be separated by blank cells. If you would start counting up from below, you'd be sure you didn't miss.

Comment: That's what he asked for - "I want to be able to loop until the cell becomes empty"

Comment: I'm not saying it is wrong. I'm only saying there's a better way to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following skeleton:

```
Sub ALoop()
    Dim r As Long
    r = 2 '//Start row
    While Len(Cells(r, "A")) > 0 '//Or While Not IsEmpty(...)
        '// Your code
        r = r + 1 '//Don't forget to increment row
    Wend
End Sub
```